# android listview item's border

Tags: android, android-drawable

good day.
today i was encounted this next problem:
i have listview:

```
 <ListView
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_view_item"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/items"/>
```

where list_view_item is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/listview_item_background">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

and listview_item_background next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <padding
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

now then i run my app i see next:

as you can see between adjacent items horizontal border are same with vertical border, but i was expected double-bordered 
[image]

then i try to set listview divider to 1dp. as expected i have three-bordered result
[image]

then i test my background drawable not in listview, but simple three linearlayout. i have expected result with double-border...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
    <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/listview_item_background"/>
    <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/listview_item_background"/>
    <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/listview_item_background"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

but in listview i still have one border. 
how i can create listview with horizontal double-border on adjacent item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i didn't fix it, but i find workaround (but in my opinion it is a cruch):
in my drawable i set bottom padding form 1dp to 2 dp